# Prototype Pollution vulnerability for location.search.substr(1)

Tags: javascript, aura, checkmarx

I have a specific code for which I am getting Prototype Pollution vulnerability in checkmark.
Here is the code

({

```
getJsonFromUrl: function(cmp,event,helper){
    var query = location.search.substr(1);
    var result = {};
    query.split("&").forEach(function(part){
        var item = part.split("=");
        result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
    });
    return result;
},
```

})

Can someone please suggest how to rewrite this piece of code to get rid of Prototype Pollution with below error.

An unsafe object assignment occurred in force-app\main\default\aura\ASKHR_CommunityArticleUpdateOrArchive\ASKHR_CommunityArticleUpdateOrArchiveHelper.js at line 7. Assigning external properties without validation may allow object properties pollution and affect application's normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype pollution occurs when a property such as `__proto__` is passed in to a method like this and it is not guarded against. This affects potentially all objects in the system and can have quite intentional effects that harm the system. At a basic level, you should consider setting only known attributes:

```
const allowed = new Set(['name','age','country']);
const result = query.split('&').reduce((p,part) => {
  const item = part.split('=',2);
  if(allowed.has(item[0])) {
    p[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  }
  return p;
}, {})
```

This allows only three properties to be copied, everything else is ignored. Other techniques are also possible, this is just one of many solutions that should get rid of this notification.